# How to add arraylist inside onDatachaned and return android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a value from onDataChanged method inside a for loop. each time whenever for loops is getting executed then the value will be added to the arraylist. now my problem is i cannot return that arraylist. it is showing null object.

```
ArrayList<BookingRequest> bookedSlot;
BookingRequest currRequet;


   req.orderByChild("b_id").equalTo("01").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                currRequet = snapshot.getValue(BookingRequest.class); // you
                bookedSlot.add(snapshot.getValue(BookingRequest.class));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });


}
```

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. The only place you can be certain the data is available, is inside the `onDataChange`. For this reason any code that needs the data from the database, must be inside `onDataChange` or be called from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Comment: Also: please don't ever leave `onCancelled` empty. While it's not the cause of the problem you have now, it may hide other problems in the future. The minimum implementation of `onCancelled` should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have tried your solution but it is still getting null outside of OnDataChanged.