# How to store arraylist inside onDatachanged and return outside android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch objects from firebase and store into arraylist.i have declared arraylist as global variable. inside onDataChanged i have added object into arraylist. so when try to access arraylist from outside any other method it is throwing null pointer exception

```
    List<BookingRequest> bookedSlot;


    private void getBookingDetails(FirebaseCallback firebaseCallback) {
    req.orderByChild("b_id").equalTo("01").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               BookingRequest currRequet = snapshot.getValue(BookingRequest.class); // you 
               bookedSlot.add(currRequest);
            }
            firebaseCallback.onCallBack(bookedSlot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
```

Interface

```
  private  interface FirebaseCallback{
    void onCallBack(ArrayList<BookingRequest> list);
}
```

Inside Oncreate method()

```
       getBookingDetails(new FirebaseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallBack(ArrayList<BookingRequest> list) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: You already asked this question earlier, and it was closed as a duplicate, but you didn't seem to change any of the content to clarify what you're observing that's not addressed by the duplicate.  Just repeating the same question won't really help - you should first try to understand the duplicate, and if that doesn't help, explain in your question why it didn't help, and what specifically you're stuck on. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59594615/how-to-add-arraylist-inside-ondatachaned-and-return-android

Comment: with the provided code, it's hard to guess what is the problem, you may provide what you are trying to do, error log, firebase structure ...etc

Comment: i have tried all other solution provided. but nothing worked so i opened new one @DougStevenson

Comment: If you don't put more detail into your question that addresses questions in the comments, it will probably just get closed again.

Comment: I am trying to fetch objects from firebase and store into arraylist.i have declared arraylist as global variable. inside onDataChanged i have added object into arraylist. so when try to access arraylist from outside any other method it is throwing null pointer exception @DougStevenson

Comment: I suggested **editing the question** with the all the details, not leaving them in a comment where they might not be seen. I also suggest explaining what exactly is in all of these variables in your code so everyone can trace through your code without guessing what's happening.

Comment: If you're tried what the duplicate shows and it doesn't work, edit your original question to show the [minimum code that reproduces where you are now stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In this question your `public void onCallBack(ArrayList<BookingRequest> list) {` implementation is empty, which means that nothing happens once the data is loaded.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen #Doug Stevenson sorry i forget to initialize the arraylist. now its working fine

Comment: @DougStevenson today i learnt how to add question in clear way. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why even you are trying to create interface because interface is useful when you want to communicate between to class but here your method is private means you are not communicating with any other class.

Try this out :

```
private void getBookingDetails() {
req.orderByChild("b_id").equalTo("01").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
           BookingRequest currRequet = snapshot.getValue(BookingRequest.class); // you 
           bookedSlot.add(currRequest);
        } 
          useBookedSlot(bookedSlot);          
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


 }


 private  useBookedSlot(List<BookSlot> bookedSlot)

{

     if(bookedSlot!==null&&bookedSlot.size()!=0)
        {
           // do your stuff
         }
}
```

Comment: getting below error.java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.fundrive.BookingCalender$3.onDataChange(BookingCalender.java:191)

Comment: You  might haven't initialised List<BlogList> . Try private List<YourClass> issues = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Thanks a lot @haresh i forget to initialised list. now its working fine.

Comment: yes sure @haresh :)